# How do I create a jagged array of windows form objects in c# converting from VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am new to both VB.net and to c#. I have managed to code an application in VB.net which works pretty well. As an exercise I wanted to do the same but in c#. This part of the application simply adds a handler to the controls so that an image and new form is display.

My code in VB is:

```
    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.frmControls = {
            {lblProdCode1, pbProd1, lblProdDesc1, lblProdRange1, lblPrice1},
            {lblProdCode2, pbProd2, lblProdDesc2, lblProdRange2, lblPrice2},
            {lblProdCode3, pbProd3, lblProdDesc3, lblProdRange3, lblPrice3},
            {lblProdCode4, pbProd4, lblProdDesc4, lblProdRange4, lblPrice4},
            {lblProdCode5, pbProd5, lblProdDesc5, lblProdRange5, lblPrice5},
            {lblProdCode6, pbProd6, lblProdDesc6, lblProdRange6, lblPrice6}}
        For Each cntr As Control In Me.frmControls
            AddHandler cntr.Click, AddressOf Me.viewProduct
        Next
```

All of this works exactly as expected. I am trying to do exactly the same thing in c#. I have tried this:

```
        {
            this.formControls[] = new object[5][];
                this.formControls[0] = object {lblProdCode1, pbProd1, lblProdDesc1, lblProdRange1, lblPrice1};
                new object[] { lblProdCode2, pbProd2, lblProdDesc2, lblProdRange2, lblPrice2},
                new object[] { lblProdCode3, pbProd3, lblProdDesc3, lblProdRange3, lblPrice3},
                new object[] { lblProdCode4, pbProd4, lblProdDesc4, lblProdRange4, lblPrice4},
                new object[] { lblProdCode5, pbProd5, lblProdDesc5, lblProdRange5, lblPrice5},
                new object[] { lblProdCode6, pbProd6, lblProdDesc6, lblProdRange6, lblPrice6}
            };
```

and the IDE VS 2019 complains with an expected ; at the first curly brace. None of the ways I have tried to declare and initialise the array with form objects seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Here are [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) about jagged arrays. It shoud be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Why `object` arrays instead of `Control` arrays?

Comment: @itsme as I said, I am new, but thanks for your advice on this, I will try and use a Control

Answer (score 0):

You should use Collection Initializer this way.

```
this.formControls[0] = new object[] {
  new object[] {lblProdCode1, pbProd1, lblProdDesc1, lblProdRange1, lblPrice1},
  new object[] { lblProdCode2, pbProd2, lblProdDesc2, lblProdRange2, lblPrice2},
  new object[] { lblProdCode3, pbProd3, lblProdDesc3, lblProdRange3, lblPrice3},
  new object[] { lblProdCode4, pbProd4, lblProdDesc4, lblProdRange4, lblPrice4},
  new object[] { lblProdCode5, pbProd5, lblProdDesc5, lblProdRange5, lblPrice5},
  new object[] { lblProdCode6, pbProd6, lblProdDesc6, lblProdRange6, lblPrice6}
};
```